# How to create MQTT broker in NestJS 9

Tags: javascript, nestjs, mqtt

When await app.startAllMicroservices() is called this error happens:

ERROR [Server] Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1883

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.connectMicroservice({
    transport: Transport.MQTT,
    options: {
      url: 'mqtt://localhost:1883',
      clientId: 'test',
    },
  });
  console.log('cp1');
  await app.startAllMicroservices(); // <-- this fails
  console.log('cp2');
  await app.listen(3000);
  console.log('Server ' + (await app.getUrl()) + ' is running');
}
```

Full code: https://github.com/SolunaSoftware/nestjs-mqtt-test

Nest.js docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application#hybrid-application

I don't understand why it does not work and any help is very appreciated.

Comment: I don't kow NestJS but I would expect that it requires you to run your own MQTT broker and this code just connects to it (given you are supplying a clientid to use when making the connection). There error implies you don't have anything listening on port 1883

Comment: Your question is about creating a broker, but your code is for a client. So what is it now? Do you want to connect a client (in nestjs) to a broker that is already running  on localhost 1883, or do you indeed want to run your own broker, wrapped -- for whatever reason -- in a nestjs app?

Comment: @ChristianFritz I want to create a broker, wrapped in a nestjs app. Sorry if my (bad/wrong) code mislead/confused you. I'm quite newbie in this area.

Answer (score 0):

That library is not for creating broker with nest.js , u can use that library for connecting to mqtt protocol , You can Use this library to create nest js broker : https://www.npmjs.com/package/pigeon-mqtt-nest

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer. I have misunderstand the way nestjs works, in my code, as hardillb says, you must provide an url to an existing (running) broker, nextjs will not start a broker for you.

To have my own broker in the backend as I would like, I could use something like aedes (https://github.com/moscajs/aedes):

```
import Aedes from 'aedes'
import { createServer } from 'net'

const port = 1883

const aedes = new Aedes()
const server = createServer(aedes.handle)

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('server started and listening on port ', port)
})
```